# Chooing earlies entry by date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an issue. I have a table that has multiple entries in it with this type of structure:

sourcename, chargesfileddate

in this table, data looks like this:

```
Michigan DOC, 20010902
Michigan DOC, 20170909
Florida DOC, 19900201
Florida DOC, 20161210
```

I'm looking to only display/export a DISTINCT sourcename with the earliest date. So, in the above example, a result set would be:

```
Florida DOC, 19900201
Michigan DOC, 20010902
```

I tried using a (SELECT MIN(chargesfiledDate)  statement, but it blew up pretty bad. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query as below:

```
Select top (1) with ties * from yourtable
    Order by row_number() over(Partition by SourceName order by chargesfileddate asc)
```

Or with subquery as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by SourceName order by ChargesFiledDate) from yourTable  ) a
Where a.RowN = 1
```